# How can I combine two array in this way

Tags: arrays, scala, merge

I have two arrays: one of them is the two dimension array

```
A = Array.ofDim[Double](2,4)  //A={(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0),(5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0)}
B = new Array[Int](2)         //B=(1,2)
```

How can I combine them in this kind of output?

```
(1 ,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0),(2 ,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0)}
```

I try the `**++** ****+:*** ***:+***` but I can do that.  Is it possible??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(A, B).zipped.map { case (a, b) => b.toDouble +: a }
```

Comment: I hope that it indeed works, in addition to being able to work ;-)

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet It works but I was hoping for answer without doing `toDouble` :). In the sense something of this type ` def conv[C,A <: C,B<:C](x: Array[Array[A]])(y: Array[B]):Array[Array[C]]`

Comment: You can omit `toDouble`, but then you get back an `Array[Array[Any]]`.